# What is the relation between the Robot framework & Python?

Tags: python-2.7, automated-tests, robotframework, atdd

What is the difference between the Robot framework and Python, and why do I need the Python language to be installed to use the Robot framework for **testing** and where do I run the Robot framework? Is it through the command line?

Comment: Have you read through the robot framework user's guide?

Answer (score 2):

The Robot Framework is a testing framework. Python is a high level programming language. The Robot Framework was written in Python, which is why you need to have Python installed first.

As for how to run and use the Robot Framework, I would recommend going through [the quick start guide](https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst).

Answer (score -2):

While writing new tests, I run Robot Framework from the command-line with

```
pybot my_test_here.txt
```

And after that, use a continuous-integration tool to run tests and report on results.

Comment: Why the `-1` ? I answered the last part of the OP's question, "... & where do i run the robot framework, is it through ( command line )?"